# How to share Vite config in monorepo?

Tags: javascript, vite, monorepo, turborepo

I am trying to make monorepo using Turborepo. I have a lot of Vue projects there and I need to share Vite config across all applications. Here's how I'm trying to achieve this.

I have package named `@monorepo/configs`:

```
packages/
  configs/
    package.json
    index.ts
    vite.config.base.ts
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@monorepo/configs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "types": "index.ts",
  "files": [
    "./src/tsconfig.base.json",
    "./src/vite.config.base.js"
  ]
}
```

vite.config.base.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

// regular config
export const ViteConfigBase = defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // some aliases
    }
  }
})
```

index.ts:

```
export { ViteConfigBase } from './vite.config.base'
```

And in the other application's vite.config.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { ViteConfigBase } from '@monorepo/configs/src/vite.config.base' // notice import from 'src'

import { defineConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig(mergeConfig(
  ViteConfigBase,
  {
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
    }
  }
))
```

Here I import ViteConfigBase as a file from 'src' folder and this is the error that I get after `npm run dev`:

```
> @monorepo/sandbox@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\apps\Sandbox\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\packages\Config\src\vite.config.base.js from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\apps\Sandbox\vite.config.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of vite.config.base.js in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\apps\Sandbox\vite.config.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

If I change import from 'src' folder to import from index, like this:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { ViteConfigBase } from '@monorepo/configs' // <-- here

import { defineConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vite'

// other config...
```

Then the error will be this:

```
> @monorepo/sandbox@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\apps\Sandbox\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\packages\Config\index.ts:1
export { ViteConfigBase } from './src/vite.config.base' 
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

OOokkay, I've seen it before. Let's try "type": "module" in package.json. Now that's the error:

```
> @monorepo/sandbox@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\apps\Sandbox\vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\Personal\monorepo\packages\Config\index.ts
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I need those files to be .ts for sure (and I'm not sure if they would work if I change extention to .js).

I could also easily fix this by just adding the build step, but I don't think it is that necessary and there should be the way around. The build step will add a lot of overhead to development process and the code itself. I've tried it and the `dist` folder was around ~4Mb for no reason. Also, I won't be able to use "Go to definition" feature in this case, and last but not least, it has to be rebuilt after every change, so I really wish to avoud this step and just use raw config files everywhere.

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you manage to solve this issue? For me helped only changing the file to `.js`. The only way it was working for me as a `.ts` file was, when I imported it from the root via relative import `../../vite.config.base.ts`. But when I moved it into a package, it was always showing some errors, same as you had

Comment: @RonaldRuzicka hello! I just gave up with the `.ts`, changed it to `.js` and it is working fine now. For your case though I am not sure really how to help :(

Comment: @RonaldRuzicka did you figure it out? :D I am struggling agains with this stuff

Answer (score 5):

If you using Turborepo, how about this way?

```
/
├── apps
|  ├── app1
|  |  ├── src
|  |  ├── package.json
|  |  └── vite.config.ts
|  └── app2
|     ├── src
|     ├── package.json
|     └── vite.config.ts
├── packages
|  └── viconfig
|     ├── index.js
|     └── package.json
```

```json
// apps/app1/package.json

{
  "name": "app1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "viconfig": "workspace:*",
    "vite": "4.0.0"
  }
}
```

```js
// apps/app1/vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import customConfig from "viconfig";

export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    ...customConfig,
  };
});
```

```js
// packages/viconfig/index.js

import path from "node:path";

export default {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src"),
    },
  },
};
```

```json
// packages/viconfig/package.json

{
  "name": "viconfig",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "types": "index.js"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Is there any other way? I need the `vite.config.base` to be a `.ts` file, because it imports other `.ts` files.